# Add row to Eloquent Collection by default based on raw query

Tags: sql, orm, laravel-4, eloquent

In my Eloquent collections, I'd like to add an extra column called "editable". "Editable" should be included in each query I run on some models. "Editable" show either be true or false, based on a raw query.

So I have a query that should be runned in each query on my models. Adding an extra column to my collection. The value of "editable" is determined by a raw query.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You need `global scope` for those models if it's query dependant.

Comment: @deczo It's not a where statement that I want to apply to all queries. If a collection for example has an id, name and description, I also want a 'editable' value. But that value should be determined by a query. It's more like an extra select that I'd like to add. And that value should be within the collection.

Comment: I think there's misconception here. A collection by default has no properties like `id`, `name` or whatever comes from the DB. Collection items, ie. Models, have those. Provide real-life example of your case and then I will be able to suggest a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add an `addSelect()` method to your query chain to include the custom attribute..

Something like

```php
$results = YourModelClass::select("*")
    ->addSelect(DB::raw("IF(condition,1,0) AS editable"))
    ->get();
```

In the above case, you would replace `condition` with your relevant SQL statement that would be evaluated per-row as part of the query.  If the statement is true, then `editable = 1` and if false then `editable = 0` for each row returned to your Collection.

EDIT: I just saw that you want this on *every* query, so you probably would need a global scope/trait for your models, but the above technique for including the extra attribute should be the correct one.

I won't copy/paste the documentation on adding global scopes, that's in the core Laravel docs and I'm sure you can find it.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a custom getter to your model:

```php
public function getEditableAttribute()
{
    /* return result from your raw query here */;
}
```

Comment: The query will need 1 parameter and also needs to be executed for each row in the collection. Besides that, "editable" is not in my table. The value of "editable" will be determined by the query.